# Analyzing a time series with R

Tags: r, time-series

I'm a newbie on R following a PDF of timeseries analysis with R, by Walter Zucchini. I have some data coming from a sensor, in particular I can have data every minutes or every 5 seconds.
Then I want to use `ts()` command to make a time series of those values. So the syntax should be `data1mints <- ts(data1min ,freq = 525600)` where 525600 are the minutes in a regular year.
after that I try to plot with this command `plot(stl(log(data1min), s.window = "periodic"))` but R says me that

> series is not periodic or has less than two periods

To be more precise, I have data from 20 March to 28 March, so i didn't have a complete year data, but I think it's a enough period to analyze what happens every minute.

What I'm wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message tells you what is wrong - you have less than 2 periods.

For example,

```
# this works since there are 3 periods
freq <- 100
ny <- 3 # no of years, i.e. periods
n <- ny * freq
set.seed(13)
tt <- ts(rnorm(n), freq = freq)
s <- stl(tt, "periodic")

# this issues error since there are less than 2 periods. (We have changed ny to 1.)
freq <- 100
ny <- 1 ##
n <- ny * freq
set.seed(13)
tt <- ts(rnorm(n), freq = freq)
s <- stl(tt, "periodic")
```

Comment: Sorry, why you use freq=100, what does it means?

Comment: That was just to make the example smaller. You can use `freq <- 525600` if you wish and it won't change the fact that the first works and the second gives an error.

Comment: Ok, thanks :) . Also i do not understand where my array of data (data1min) as written above, must be inserted in your example and what period i must use if I want to make as periods the minutes (i.e all the minutes of my 8 days?)

Comment: The example is self contained and as stated in the first sentence intended to illustrate the error message which states that you must provide at least two periods of data.  You don't have to insert anything.   To run it just copy and paste it into R.

Comment: The example works, and it's ok. But my question is if it's possible, having data coming from 8 days only, analyze it in some way, also without ts function. Thanks

Comment: The frequency is the number of data points in a period so if you set frequency such that a period is one day then with 8 days you have 8 periods which is more than two periods so you are ok.  If frequency is such that a week is a period or a month is a period or a year is a period then obviously you don't have two periods so you are not ok.