# error in stl .series is not periodic

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, trend

I am pretty sure I am missing something which is very simple but still not able to figure out why this error is showing up .
The data I have is of every month end data from 2013 Apr to 2014 Mar. Now I want to understand the trend over the 12 months period .

```
xx <- structure(c(41.52, 41.52, 41.52, 41.68, 41.68, 41.68, 41.84, 
41.84, 41.84, 42.05, 42.05, 42.05), .Tsp = c(2013.25, 2014.16666666667, 
12), class = "ts");
```

is my time series data .
Now when I use

```
 stl(xx,s.window ="periodic")
```

I get error :

```
Error in stl(xx, s.window = "periodic") : 
  series is not periodic or has less than two periods
```

i am not sure what is wrong as I understand the series has 12 periods .Please assist

Comment: Your time series is too short. You need two years (= two periods in your case) of data, at least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The terminology is a little misleading. In R, the `frequency` is the number of observations in one "period". For monthly data, `frequency=12` and you have just one period. You need two periods, or 24 observations, to use `stl()`.

Comment: Ok Rob Now I understood what I was missing . Thanks  .+`1

Comment: @Pascal yes but until you edited I did not understand  what exactly you meant  "Your time series is too short."

Comment: @Bg1850  Anyway, you could have search first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615254/analyzing-a-time-series-with-r, for example

Comment: I have a time series with frequency = 288 (sampling each 5 min) and 29 days(so the number of observation is 8352), but I still got this error, why?